# Unity C# text not changing

Tags: c#, user-interface, animation, unity-game-engine, text

I have a text box that fades in and out and changes colour depending on the animation, this works well enough, but the text doesn't change when i tell it to. I tried some other Stack answers, but they didn't work. Below is the script that contains the code that SHOULD change the text. I have been on this for ages and my brain hurts, mostly because of the animation (parameters and transitions mostly).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Objectives : MonoBehaviour {
#region Variables
public bool CompletedAnim1;
public bool StonesFallen;
public bool IceFallen;
public Objective ObjectiveRef;
public Text PlankText;
public AnimController AnimContRef;
public TextController TextContRef;
string NewText;
#endregion Variables

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    CompletedAnim1 = false;
    NewText = "Drop All Ice";
    PlankText.SetAllDirty();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (StonesFallen)
        ObjectiveRef.ObjectiveCompleted = true;

    if (StonesFallen && IceFallen)
    {
        PlankText.text = "Drop All Ice";
        ObjectiveRef.ObjectiveCompleted = false;
        AnimContRef.SetTriggerParameter("FadeIn");
        Debug.Log("Ice and Stones Fallen");
    }

    if (CompletedAnim1)
    {
        PlankText.text = NewText;
        Debug.Log("CompletedAnim1");
        Debug.Log(PlankText.text);
        PlankText.SetAllDirty();
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a string to `PlankText.text` twice in all the script, once inside `if (StonesFallen && IceFallen)` and once inside `if (CompletedAnim1)`.

Problem is that you always assign to it the string `"Drop All Ice"`, the first time using the string, and the second time using `NewText`, which contains the same string.

And it can't be that `NewText` changes its value outside the script, because it's `private`, unless you cut out part of the class in your post.

Comment: I changed it like this `if (CompletedAnim1)
        {
            PlankText.text = "Drop All Ice";
            Debug.Log("CompletedAnim1");
            Debug.Log(PlankText.text);
            PlankText.SetAllDirty();
        }`       and completely commented out the other if statement                **no dice**

Comment: Then your question isn't clear at all, please tell exactly when you want to change the `PlankText.text`, and from which `string` to which `string`. It seemed that you wanted to change the text from the start of the fade in animation to its completion.

Comment: i want to change the text from it's current text to a new text, the CompletedAnim1 bool is changed to true after a 5 second delay from when i start the animation.

Comment: I asked you specifically **WHEN** you want to change the text. No one can help you if you can't manage to explain your problem in a detailed way.

Comment: I tried to clarify. I thought it was fairly obvious that I wanted to change the text when the Boolean changed to true, or as I stated after my Coroutine in another script changes it to true after a 5 second delay. There's no need to get salty :|

Comment: @GamingGecko `NewText` contains the text `"Drop All Ice"`, so when you set `PlankText.text = NewText;` you're getting that text. The reason it doesn't "change" is because `PlankText.text = "Drop All Ice";`!  That is, `A := A, A == A ∴ No Change`

Comment: I'm sorry, but i forgot to add the text is originally "Drop All Stones"